# REST API is not returning any servers despite the servers being visible from the New Relic Dashboard

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am trying to Get a list of all servers on my New Relic account through the REST API but only an empty list is being returned. I can be able to see the Servers/Hosts from New Relic Dashboard. What might be the Issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the New Relic support team, this was the solution

> If you are using this endpoint:
>   https://api.newrelic.com/v2/servers.json, it is for the New Relic
>   Servers product, which has been discontinued. If you are using New
>   Relic Infrastructure, you may [get a list of servers from Insights](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/insights-api/get-data/query-insights-event-data-api):
>
> SELECT uniques(hostname) FROM SystemSample If you are not using
>   Infrastructure, you may get a list of host names associated with your
>   APM applications:
>
> SELECT uniques(host) FROM Transaction